# Python log viewer GUI

Tags: python, file, logging, viewer

I am new with python and I'd like to build a GUI where I could see three or four logs files at the same time generated from any others applications. I used to do a `less` command to see the log files from the other application, but I have many logs files, and it is difficult to identify the errors.

Any comments/suggestions please?

Answer (score 5):

[cutelog](https://github.com/Busimus/cutelog) might be a great choice in your purpose.

The minimal setup is

#### install & run cutelog

```
pip install cutelog
```

On windows, the `cutelog.exe` can be found inside your `<path_to_python>/Scripts` folder.

#### Configure your logging

You need to add a `SocketHandler` to your logger.

```py
import logging 
from logging.handlers import SocketHandler

# The root logger. Could be any logger you have existing in your app.
logger = logging.getLogger()
socket_handler = SocketHandler("127.0.0.1", 19996)  # default listening address
logger.addHandler(socket_handler)
```

Comment: cutelog requires a local X server.  I am running on WSL2 and don't currently have access to an X server.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) (python bindings for Qt) and perhaps use four `QTableWidget` panes to keep track of the four log files. But that's just personal preference. Python also has bindings for the Wx windowing toolkit, for GTK and for Tk.

Comment: There's PySide (alternative bindings for Qt, with a more commercially-liberal license) if licensing PyQt is an issue. I think OP should pick one and study it. As far as documentation goes, PySide (http://www.pyside.org) wins out over PyQt (since it references the C++ Qt documentation if memory serves)